# Accessing J2EE Session Beans in a GWT Service Implementation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt

I have a GWT web client.

And a J2EE business layer.

I would like to access the J2EE Session bean in the GWT service implementation.

The code I am working with is below:

```
public class TestServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements TestService {

@EJB
private AudioItemFacade audioItemFacade;  
private AudioItem audioItem;

  @Override
  public String myMethod(String s) throws Exception {
     Object id = 1L;
     audioItem = audioItemFacade.find(id);
     return "Server says: " + s + " " + audioItem.toString();
  }

}
```

It currently does not connect to the database and return the correct value.

Comment: Is @EJB injection working correctly? Do you get any error message?

Comment: Hello it appears to be working now.